# How can I make form fields / messages available for given locale in Symfony 4?

Tags: forms, symfony, locale, translation

I created a form in Symfony 4:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($item)

->add('username', TextType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')))
```

But now I get an error message for `username`.

> These messages are not available for the given locale and cannot be
>   found in the fallback locales. Add them to the translation catalogue
>   to avoid Symfony outputting untranslated contents.

So I installed Symfony translation via composer, I still cannot find the "catalogue" and also why do I need to add this to a catalogue if I only have one language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Profiler you can see which catalogue symfony is looking for. normally validation is found in the validators catalogue, which means you need to add a validators.LOCALE.yml (locale must be the locale you are using ex. en) in the translations folder. But look up the right catalogue!

Comment: I do not see any indication in the profiler for the catalogue: https://i.imgur.com/Btv7k68.png

Comment: the catalouge is in the domain colum.

Comment: Ok, this means, the catalogue name is "messages". So if I understand you right, then I have to add this file: `config/packages/validators.LOCALE.yml`